Determinant of an $L$-endomorphism seen as a $K$-endomorphism for an extension $L/K$.
Suppose $L/K$ is a finite extension of degree $r$ and $M\in\mathscr{M}_n(L)$, one can construct a matrix $M'\in\mathscr{M}_{nr}(K)$ by identifying $L$ with $K^r$, namely : $M'$ is the matrix of the endomorphism $X\mapsto MX$ of the $K$-vector space $L^n$, in some $K$-basis of $L^n$. My question is : what does $M'$ look like ? In particular, I believe that $\det(M')=N_{L/K}(\det M)$ by looking at some examples, what is the characteristic polynomial of $M'$ ? this would immediately imply the determinant formula above. If we look at the simple example $K=\mathbb{R}$ and $L=\mathbb{C}$, this amounts to say that
$$ \begin{vmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{vmatrix}=|\det(A+iB)|^2 $$
for all $A,B\in\mathscr{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$. We can prove this using the elementary operations $C_j\leftarrow C_j+iC_{n+j}$ for $j\leqslant n$, this gives
$$ \begin{vmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} A-iB & -B \\ B+iA & A \end{vmatrix} $$
and then $L_j\leftarrow L_j-iL_{j-n}$ for $j>n$, this gives
$$ \begin{vmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} A-iB & -B \\ 0 & A+iB \end{vmatrix}=|\det(A+iB)|^2. $$
I don't know if this argument can be easily adapted to a more general situation.

The identity $\det(M') = N_{L/K}(\det(M))$ certainly holds if $M$ is diagonalisable. Indeed, if $X_1, \dots, X_n$ is basis of eigenvectors of $M$ with $M X_i = \lambda_i X_i$, then $\det(M) = \prod_i \lambda_i$. We can make a $K$-basis of $L^n$ by taking scalar multiples of the $X_i$ vectors. W.r.t. this basis $M'$ is block diagonal, where block $i$ represents the $K$-linear map $L \to L: x \mapsto \lambda_i x$. This block has determinant $N_{L/K}(\lambda_i)$.
Perhaps the general formula can be proven similarly be making $M$ triangular over an the algebraic closure of $L$.

More generally, suppose $K$ is a field and $A\subseteq K^{r\times r}$ a commutative subring. Let $M\in A^{n\times n}$. Then it is a general result that $\det_K M=\det_K(\det_A M)$

See the references here.
